# Limit involving sin

Tags: calculus, limits, trigonometry

The question is

$$\lim_{t\to0}{{1\over 2+ \sin (t)}-{1\over 2}\over \sin (t)}$$

since I cannot directly substitute, how would I go about factoring the $\sin t$. Any help is appreciated!

Comment: I edited your question, but I am not sure if this is the correct meaning of your question. Is this what you wanted to ask?

Comment: Sorry, I was just going about re-editing it. My apologies!

Answer (score 2):

**Hint :**

Cross multiply the numerator, we will obtain
$$
\frac1{2+\sin t}-\frac12=-\frac{\sin t}{2(2+\sin t)}.
$$
Hence
$$
\frac{\frac1{2+\sin t}-\frac12}{\sin t}=-\frac{\sin t}{2(2+\sin t)}\cdot\frac1{\sin t}.
$$

Comment: Thank you for the great help!

Comment: I must have missed "cross multiplication" when we covered $field$ axioms in class.

Answer (score 1):

Factoring?
$$\frac{\frac{1}{2+\sin t}-\frac{1}{2}}{\sin t}=\frac{\frac{-\sin t}{2(2+\sin t)}}{\sin t}=\frac{-1}{4+2\sin t}$$
Can you guess now what the limit is?

Comment: Wow. Thank you very much! Very very much!

Comment: You're welcome :)

Answer (score 1):

\begin{align}
\frac{\frac{1}{2+\sin t} - \frac 12}{\sin t}
& = -\frac{\sin t}{2(2 + \sin t)\sin t} = -\frac{1}{2(2 + \sin t)}.
\end{align}

Answer (score 0):

Hint:
$\sin t \approx t$ as $t\rightarrow 0$.

Comment: -1: This, while true, does not seem to be relevant to the problem.

Comment: @J.J. Of course it's relevant, if the OP doesn't know how to factor simple stuff then I don't know what he is doing with limits, so I assumed this is what he was struggling with...

Comment: This shows that "substitution" is possible. But by "directly substitute" the asker clearly means the expression can't be evaluated at the point in question. For which this substitution (nor any other) won't help.

Comment: @JanHudec I think this discussion comes to the question when to assume triviality in a question, while the other answers in this case answered the question, any rational reader will assume triviality in those answers as they involve fundamental algebra (in this context of limits) .